# bash: 'cut' command field separator

Tags: bash, cut

`count=1;echo "Hello Bash"| cut -d" " -f$count`

The above command gives error stating that: "*Try 'cut --help' for more information.*"

The error is because of using variable "$count" with field separator(-f$count).

Are variables not allowed with field separator? Is this the problem with  cut command or Am I missing something?

PS: I am using Linux Kernel version 2.3

Comment: That *exact* command is giving you an error? Because it works here. Are you perhaps trying `count=1 echo "Hello Bash"| cut -d" " -f$count` instead? Because that rightly shouldn't work since the assignment isn't visible (for a number of reasons) to the cut command line.

Comment: I am using the exact command as I posted. @EtanReisner: Is this because I am using an older kernel version?

Comment: @GopeshBharadwaj, it certainly cannot be kernel-related. Run `set -x` first and update your question with the output when you execute your command. Ideally, copy and paste both the exact input and the exact (`set -x` enabled) output.

Comment: No, as stated the kernel is not at all relevant here. The shell version might be (but even that isn't likely) this should work fine if used as is in bash. Are you perhaps using some other shell that might have different variable scope behaviour? What do you get as exact output if you run `set -x` and then copy and paste the command from your question?

Comment: ...that said, unquoted variable expansions do, as a rule, invite bugs, so the advice you were given (in the rejected and now-deleted answers) to quote `"$count"` was in fact good.

Comment: This could fail if `$IFS` contained the character `1`, but that's... unlikely; also, were it true, adding quotes would have fixed things. I'm wondering if there's an alias or function at play; in any event, `set -x` should make it clear.

Comment: @GopeshBharadwaj: what does it say *before* it says you should try `cut --help`? There should be a line with an actual error message.

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that the cause of your problem is shell related. Some old shells may actually have a bug when expanding variables in compound commands separated by semicolon i.e. variables given an assignment may expand with an old value on the same line:

```
count=1;echo "Hello Bash"| cut -d" " -f$count  ## $count may still be empty here 
echo "$count"  ## already 1
```

Somehow piping may also be a contributing factor.

Of course all that if `echo "Hello Bash"| cut -d" " -f1` actually works. If not it's `cut` that's to be blamed. Perhaps you need to add spaces after `-d` and `-f` before their arguments.